# SQL syntax error from book

Tags: mysql

I'm very new at SQL, and I'm using this code from a book. However, it's return an error. Any advice on how to fix? Thanks.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
SUM(CASE WHEN state <> state2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as numsame
FROM zipcensus zc
```

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(CASE WHEN state <> state2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as numsame FROM zipcensus zc' at line 2**

Comment: firstly, you need a comma between the count and the sum clause.  Secondly, you need to hit the table twice, once for the count and then for the sum.  What your query is asking doesn't really make sense.  You want a count of all the rows in zipcensus and then a count of rows where state is not the same as state2?

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(a.*) totalcount, count(b.*) numsame
from zipcensus a
   , zipcensus b
where b.state=b.state2;
```

By the way, depending on how many rows are in zipcensus, this will not perform very well, even with indexes on state and state2 - it's going to full table scan in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
SUM(CASE WHEN state <> state2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as numsame
FROM zipcensus zc
```

Comma error, you need a comma between the count and the sum clause.